# What is the error in this html code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, html-lists

I am taking a class with Code Academy on html and css. Right now I am on the section dealing with bootstrap and I am stuck. The directions are to add the "pull-left" class to the first ul element and then the "pull-right" element to the second ul element. My code seems good to me but whenever I try to save and submit it gives me the error: "Oops, try again. Add the class "pull-right" to the second ul element."

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here because I definitely have added the "pull-right" class to the second ul element.

```
<ul class="pull-left">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Browse</a></li></ul>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pull-right">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
     </ul>  
    </ul>
```

Does anyone know why code academy is giving me this error??!!

Comment: That's invalid HTML, classes or no classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had too many `<\ul>` tags from what I could see. Try this and see if it's any better

```
<ul class="pull-left">
    <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out one of the  tags under Browse and above "pull-right" class.